# Can minecraft skins be used on different Xbox accounts?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

For example, if I purchase and download them on my account, can someone else playing minecraft on their account on the same xbox also use them?

Comment: I didn't even know you could have skins in the 360 version. My interest level just skyrocketed!

Comment: @Fluttershy They're still DLC, not custom. The game comes with one "skin pack" by default, and you can get [Skin Pack 2](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Skin-Pack-2/ef7480da-8946-40a8-8c8f-6331b589bb4d?cid=SLink) to increase the selection for 160MSP.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

Xbox 360 DLC is linked to the purchasing console and the purchasing account, i.e., all accounts on the Xbox 360 that purchased the DLC can use it, and the purchasing account can re-download and use it on any other Xbox *as long as it stays connected to the Internet*.

I tested the trial skins with another account on the same Xbox 360, and I could use them just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No they cant they stay on your account

Comment: Have you tested this? I found the opposite